# 'Serial1' was not declared in this scope for automatic plant watering

Tags: arduino-uno

```cpp
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
int in1 = 2;
int in2 = 3;
LiquidCrystal lcd(14,15,16,17,18,19);
int led = 13;
int flag = 0;
int motorpin = 11;
int sensorpin = 7;

void setup()
{
  lcd.begin(16,2);
  Serial1.begin(9600);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motor, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(sensor, INPUT_PULLUP);
  lcd.print("Plant Watering");
  lcd.setCursor(4,1);
  delay(2000);
  lcd.clear()
  lcd.print("RCC INSTITUTE");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("Starting....");
  delay(2000);
  gsmInit();
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("System Ready");
}

void loop()
{
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Automatic Mode");
  if (digitalRead(sensor) == 1 && flag == 0)
  {
    delay(1000);
    if (digitalRead(sensor) == 1)
    {
      digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
      sendSMS("Low Soil Moisture detected. Motor turned ON");
      lcd.begin(16, 2);
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print("Motor ON ");
      digitalWrite(motor, HIGH);
      delay(2000);
      flag=1;
    }
  } else if(digitalRead(sensor) == 0 && flag == 1)
  {
    delay(1000);
    if (digitalRead(sensor) == 0)
    {
      digitalWrite(led, LOW);
      sendSMS("Soil Moisture is Normal. Motor turned OFF"); 
      digitalWrite(motor, LOW);
      lcd.begin(16, 2);
      lcd.print("Motor OFF");
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print("Motor OFF");
      delay(2000);
      flag = 0;
    }
  }
}

void sendSMS(String msg)
{
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Sending SMS");
  Serial1.println("AT+CMGF=1");
  delay(500);
  Serial1.print("AT+CMGS=");
  Serial1.print('"');
  Serial1.print("+918xxxxxxxxx"); // number
  Serial1.print('"');
  Serial1.println();
  delay(500);
  Serial1.println(msg);
  delay(500);
  Serial1.write(26);
  delay(1000);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("SMS Sent");
  delay(1000);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
}

void gsmInit()
{
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Finding Module..");
  boolean at_flag = 1;
  while (at_flag)
  {
    Serial1.println("AT");
    while (Serial1.available() > 0)
    {
      if (Serial1.find("OK"))
      at_flag = 0;
    }
    delay(1000);
  }
  Serial1.println("ATE0"); //<=== it says 'Serial1' was not declared in this scope
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Finding Network..");
  boolean net_flag = 1;
  while(net_flag)
  {
    Serial1.println("AT+CPIN?");
    while(Serial1.available() > 0)
    {
      if (Serial1.find("READY"))
        net_flag = 0;
      break;
    }
    delay(1000);
  }
  Serial1.println("AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0");
  delay(1000);
  Serial1.println("AT+CMGF=1");
  delay(1000);
  Serial1.println("AT+CSMP=17,167,0,0");
  lcd.clear();
  Serial1.flush();
}
```

Comment: UNO has no Serial1, so what did you expect?

Comment: 1. The Uno has no Serial1. Just use `Serial`. 2. When asking about a compilation error on this site, you always have to include the complete error message, including information, where the error happened.

Comment: As an aside: in gsmInit(), the `break` isn't inside the `if (Serial1.find("READY"))` for lack of `{}`; possible bug.

Comment: FYI I flagged an admin to purge the phone number from your code.

Answer (score 1):

The UNO only has one serial port, named `Serial`.  You can create another one using SoftwareSerial (which you have included but not used) and you can, if you choose, name this `Serial1`.

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial Serial1(4, 5); // RX, TX
```